# How to draw a line with faded ends?

Tags: qt, qml, line, fade, rectangles

I'm trying to draw a line with faded ends in QML, similar to this one:

[image: A faded ends white line on a black background]

I tried drawing the line using a rectangle but I don't know how to fade out the ends.

I am using Qt 5.12.

Comment: Didn't you need your line to have pointy sides or just be faded? The answers won't generate the exact output like your example image. And, as another note, the offsets provided in the answers will change with line length. Is this what you needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Rectangle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html#gradient-prop) item both with [Gradient](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gradient.html), for example:

```js
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"

        Rectangle {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: 400
            height: 5
            border.width: 0
            gradient: Gradient {
                orientation: Gradient.Horizontal
                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "black" }
                GradientStop { position: 0.25; color: "white" }
                GradientStop { position: 0.75; color: "white" }
                GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "black" }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `RadialGradient`:

```
    RadialGradient {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 400
        height: 5
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "white" }
            GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: "black" }
        }
    }
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAABfHicjU9LrsIwDNz3FBYHqLqgm7BECLHjcwKThsQixFFqxAL17rh8ip7E4s3KHo/HY7pkLgI72V3Jniv609ZLTlI49l++XfIlo9TrgjmQxbg6nZyVvtqid3CvQHFEe/aFr6kzsNchJh91BpYjFwOzY1TBDIaneI8dYVS7jlySt8MITDZw6WurtCubZCBj0XoS3KiTYGDeNBMVHPkgBtqJ8W9jAz9OjPjQB+GsGTP3JMR6rambxRT5FkjcJ/I/VtvF729HvKqhGh7hBnMF)